# GO API installation fails "evq/chromaticity"

Tags: go

I am trying to install chromaticity on my own machine for testing, and no matter what i do i will always hit the error seen in this picture [installation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frx8O.png)
I dont know why it happened i tried searching but i found nothing online. my question is does anyone know why it happens? or can point me to the right direction? i have checked the folders and yes there are no GO files in there but i dont see why that is a problem

The api could be found here: https://github.com/evq/chromaticity

Comment: Can you try running `go install github.com/evq/chromaticity` and then check if `chromacity` command is available or if it was created in `$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: hey thanks for the fast reply, this still gives me the same error as the picture, and no $GOPATH/bin doesnt have it

Comment: @mkopriva I have it setup exactly as it is on github didnt remove or modify anything in the files. let me clarify: i followed the steps:1-  go get github.com/evq/chromaticity
2- go install github.com/evq/chromaticity
3- chromaticity  but it keeps failing at step 2. i also did get all the packages needed too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue (as in bug) on the project, rather an issue due to lack of documentation on how to build the project itself.

If you look at the `Makefile` file on the root directory, you'll notice that `static/static.go` is a generated file as part of the build process. Such file is usually not committed to the repo so you'll need to build it yourself. To do so, you'll need to have [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) installed.

Here's what you need to do in order to build the project successfully:

1. Get the `go-bindata` package

   ```
   go get -u github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...
   ```
2. Get the project

   ```
   go get github.com/evq/chromaticity
   ```
3. Go the project root directory

   ```
   cd [...the chromaticity project root..]
   ```
4. Run `make` to generate the `static/static.go` file

   ```
   make
   ```
5. Build/ install the project

   ```
   go install
   ```

---

**Update**:

Noticed from your screenshot that you're using `Windows`, in that case you  may need to workaround the issue of running `Makefile` in `Windows`. See here for possible solution: [How to run a makefile in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715841/how-to-run-makefile-in-windows)

Comment: i have done what you said using mingw32-make but i get the following error back  `cp -R swagger-ui/dist static/apidocs
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp -R swagger-ui/dist static/apidocs, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'static/apidocs' failed
mingw32-make: *** [static/apidocs] Error 2`  do you have any ideas on why that is? i tried searching the error and i have got 1 solution about the installation is not clean, i deleted and reinstalled but same problem

Comment: using -d in the command and reading the output i find 
`process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cp -R swagger-ui/dist static/apidocs, ...) failed.`

Comment: @mohammedmallah the `swagger-ui` folder in `chromaticity` is a git submodule, it should be initialized  when you run `make`, but just to confirm do you see any files inside the `swagger-ui` folder?

Comment: yeah the swagger-ui contains files

Comment: @mohammedmallah What folder/files exist inside the `static` folder after you run `make`?

Comment: Nothing no changes whatsoever. Make just exists with error 2 and no changes happened

Comment: If you run `cp -R swagger-ui/dist static/apidocs` in the project root directory, does it produces any error?

Comment: i tried using cygwin instead and that did the trick  i dont know why but now it is functioning. All i have to do now is actually figure out working with the thing. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue when trying to "get" and then install this project. I looked into the code and there is no trace of `Asset()` function in `github.com/evq/chromaticity/static`. Moreover git history does not show any .go files in `static/` directory. Personally, I would create issue in the project and/or look for different repo containing desired functionality.

Comment: will do, unfortunately it is the only api i know of that can control KiNet protocol (evq/go-kinet doesnt work and the python version is filled with errors) so lets hope i can figure out something with this.

Comment: @mohammedmallah this seems to be the culprit https://github.com/evq/chromaticity/blob/94c718daad637dc52c2e03f742476ee7b1dde18d/.gitignore#L14